# Referencing resource ID from the support library in XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library

importing an xml file that uses a resource id created in the v7 supoort library.

The imported xml file contains the following  id but it does not use the "@id+," as if it were just created:

**android:id="@id/activity_chooser_view_content"**

At the following link it shows that in v7 appCompat Support library the id has been created (3rd line down after end of comments section):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_activity_chooser_view.xml

```
 android:id="@+id/activity_chooser_view_content"
```

What would i Have to do in order to get Android or Android Studio to find the id?

I get the following errors:

```
Error:(2, 51) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/activity_chooser_view_content').

Error:(8, 64) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/image').
```

I am compiling the following reference libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0'
```

Comment: Since you're just assigning the ID to your layouts, you can just do `android:id="@+id/activity_chooser_view_content` yourself.  The `+` will add the ID to the R file. There's also no need to use support library IDs if you don't want to. They're only used for referencing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference an ID from the SDK, you need `@android:id/<name>`

Alternatively, you error means that since you have `@id` and not `@+id`, you are trying to reference an existing ID **from your own app's resources**, not create a new one.

Or maybe you should try something like

```
View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.abc_activity_chooser_view);
View x = rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.<name>);
```

---

Worth mentioning ...

> Internal layouts are not meant to be used directly and are subject to change at any time, which may break your code in the future. The better solution is to create your own layout or use a public framework widget with similar functionality. Use of an internal widget is done at your own risk

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39318656/2308683

Comment: This is in the support library.  Not the SDK. I'm not sure why he wants to use a reference ID in a custom layout though.

Comment: I was just thinking about that... Not sure, either

Comment: I am importing Chromium layouts and I have litterally 100's of layout id's that are not being found. As you say here: "In order to reference an ID from the SDK, you need @android:id/<name>" that is what is done. For example: android:id="@id/expand_activities_button" but they are not found.

Comment: I could add the plus but wouldn't that mean that its not going to have the characteristic inherited with the id?

Comment: That is not what is done. `@android:id` is not the same as `@id`

Comment: I just updated the post. apologies. the id shown above now matches the id created the support library xml at the link. I pasted the wrong id. apologies again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "inherited", but yes, you'd be defining your own resource identifier instead of referencing another one with a plus

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: For example, the default `ListActivity` would use `@android:id/list`, which is an ID from the default XML of the SDK. If you defined your own XML file with a value of `@+id/list`, then app would crash because it expects the other one.

Comment: When I add the  "android:id=@android:id/" in front of the id. it produces a different set of resources in the autocomplete. verses just "android:id=@id/" Neither shows the resource I need (that is used in the imported xml file). I will figure it out. thanks. I just wonder how the Chromium folks do it.

Comment: Correct, the autocomplete is using Android SDK resources, not your own. For internal views, I doubt you'll be able to find the necessary ID. Chromium is open source, I thought? And they probably have their own forums which could help more.